# Web App V Win App - Display differences

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, layout

I have been searching for any info on this without success.

I am updating an application that has two versions.  A WPF windows app and an MVC web app. The requirement is that they must look the same.

Why when I add an image of, say, 100px X 100px to both the image in the web app looks larger than the image in the win app?

If I add margins the space between the items looks more in the win app than it does in the web app.

I thought I was mistaken so I physically measured both and confirmed the differences.

I want the 100X100 image in both apps to look the same and do not want to up size as this will distort the image.

Can anyone explain why this would happen and any way I can get around it?

Many Thanks

Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no styling is being applied to the images either in XAML or CSS, they could still be different because WPF pixels are device independent.

I guess you could set the ScaleTransform of your WPF app to match the desired size, but remember this will be different depending on monitor size and Windows DPI settings.

Comment: Thanks Gaz, after a little more research into what you have said here it does explain why I am seeing differences.